# Wi-FI Connection Issues

Tags: networking, wireless

on my Ubuntu system, it won't connect to any wi-fi network even those that are easily connected using my android phone or my windows system I don't have access to any ethernet connections at this time but I was wondering if anyone could help me diagnose this issue I don't know the commands to be able to post what my system says about it and upload it to you if you te3ll me the commands I will gladly check them and post screenshots of the results. I am completely new to using any flavour of Linux so my knowledge about it is very limited. I am running version 20.04 LTS freshly downloaded and installed

Comment: WiFi hardware issues are usually specific to the particular model wifi adapter that you have. You should start your research using the model as a search term. If you'd like additional help, you should also provide that information in the body of your question.

Comment: Maybe `iwconfig` to start? Then try `iwlist <device> scanning`?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.